# Что значит "машу каслом не испортишь"?

Tags: фраза

Вы можете найти в интернете: [https://www.google.com/search?q=машу+каслом+не+испортишь](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%83+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C)

Что это значит?

Comment: Usually when you provide an evidence of some prior research, the probability of getting more up-votes is higher.

Comment: Крепок задок, да слаба на передок (с) Маша.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ну изначально, "кашу маслом не испортишь", ну а смысл прост..... Кашу не возможно испортить маслом, это знают все:-) но есть другие примеры, когда добавление компонента или действия не повредит.

Answer (score 7):

The origin. This is a slip-of-the-tongue expression from an anecdote. The reply to it was "смотря каким каслом!" (= depends on how good that "касл" is), as if the first phrase (which is a distorted version of the well-known proverb "Кашу маслом не испортишь" ~ 'It's never too much butter in porridge') had literally meant 'You can't make a woman of Masha using some non-existent "касл" thing'. The other person in their reply definitely meant something at a real man's disposal.

Also, for proper understanding one needs to know the expression "испортить девушку" (to make a woman of a girl): the literal meaning of 'spoiling' here is that a girl would be a virgin no more.

Answer (score 4):

кашу маслом не испортишь

Толкование Перевод
1кашу маслом не испортишь 
кашу (каши) маслом не испортишь
посл.
cf. never too much of a good thing; plenty is no plague; good counsel does no harm
Глумов. Я, кажется, в разговоре с ним пересолил немного... Ещё молод, увлекаюсь... Ну, да это не мешает, кашу маслом не испортишь. (А. Островский, На всякого мудреца довольно простоты) — Glumoy. Talking to him I laid it too thick, I reckon... Well, I am still young and easily carried away... No harm done, though. Never too much of a good thing.
Русско-английский фразеологический словарь
2кашу маслом не испортишь 
• КАШУ <-и> МАСЛОМ НЕ ИСПОРТИШЬ{{}}

## [saying]

⇒ sth. good or useful cannot be harmful, even in large amounts:
- - butter never spoils the porridge;
- you can't spoil porridge with butter;
- you can't have too much of a good thing.
     ♦ ...Товарищ Коба провозгласил первый тост: "Дорогие друзья, - сказал он, - я пригласил вас сюда для того, чтобы... отметить самую короткую ночь..." - "Ура!" - крикнул Вершилов. "Не спеши, - поморщился Коба. - ...Я также хочу провозгласить тост за самого мудрого нашего деятеля..." Вершилов на всякий случай хотел ещё раз крикнуть "ура", зная, что каши маслом не испортишь, но товарищ Коба на этот раз успел плюнуть прямо в открытый для выкрика рот (Войнович 5). Comrade Koba proposed the first toast. "Dear friends," he said, "I invited you here to celebrate...the shortest night of the year. ..." "Hurrah!" cried Vershilov. "Not so fast," said Comrade Koba, knitting his brows... .I also want to propose a toast to our wisest statesman. ..." Vershilov was about to shout "Hurrah!" just to be on the safe side, realizing that butter never spoils the porridge, but this time Comrade Koba managed to spit directly into Vershilov's open mouth (5a).
Большой русско-английский фразеологический словарь

Comment: Поручик Ржевский в театре.Молодой актер впервые на сцене,по роли должен произнести
одну-единственную фразу "кашу маслом не испортишь". От волнения он говорит:
- Машу каслом не испортишь.
Поручик:
- Смотря каким каслом!

Comment: Кашу маслом не испортишь. Машу каслом не испортишь. Комический эффект в  анекдоте  о поручике Ржевском достигается с помощью перемены позиций буквы "к" и буквы "м" в словах "кашу" и "маслом". В результате этого в анекдоте появляется грубовато-сексуальный смысл (или подтекст), как во всех анекдотах о поручике Ржевском. Слово "касл" здесь воспринимается как мужской половой член, и речь в анекдоте идёт о том, половым членом какого размера ("смотря каким каслом", то есть смотря какой размер "касла", что означает - смотря какой размер мужского полового члена) можно "испортить" Машу (девушку.)

Comment: Комический эффект в анекдоте про поручика Ржевского достигается изменением позиций буквы "К" и букве "м" в слове "каша" и "нефтяной". В результате, в анекдоте появляется в его грубой сексуальной значения (или оттенок), как и во всех шутках о лейтенанта Ржева. Слово "замок" воспринимается как мужской пенис, и это шутка о пенисе, что размер ("это зависит от того, как касл", то есть зависит от размера "касл", что означает - в зависимости от размера мужского члена) может "испортить" (лишить девственности, невинности) девушка Маша.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the answer of @Матвей Дёмин has gotten a downvote, but it is in essence right. There is an adage "кашу маслом не испортишь", which means that something would be very useful (at least not harmful) in some situation, meal, product or whatever. It is usually used with a bit of humor. (Literally it says that you cannot make any harm to porridge with oil)

For instance, recently a neighbor of mine asked me to print one text for him. As he is a retiree and has bad sight he needed a font to be large, but he had  not specified the size. So I printed with a size of 30, which is enormously large, and I could say in this case "кашу маслом не испортишь".

But you have provided slightly another words "машу каслом не испортишь". This can be either an error, messing the first letters in the first two words, or (more likely) a deliberate pun. I see nothing funny in it without a context, but I can suppose that it is somehow related to some Masha (Маша), which is a female name. So it might be some situation where these word were used toward some girl, and they were supposed to be funny.

There is no word "касло", so this phrase has no serious meaning.

Answer (score 2):

A proverb (**кашу маслом не испортишь**) spoonerised, yielding *Маша* and the non-word *касло*; however, given the presence of a female name and the verb *испортить*, the whole thing defaults to innuendo so that all manner of frivolous meanings could be read into *касло* (which, I should stress, doesn't "sound like anything" per se).

Not a terribly intelligent piece of humour, I'm afraid.